# Does the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}(x^n+x^{-n})$ converges for $x\in[\frac{1}{2},2]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}(x^n+x^{-n})$ converge for $x\in[\frac{1}{2},2]$?

I think that it does but not uniformly.

Since $$\left| \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}(x^n+x^{-n})\right|=\left| \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}\right||x^n+x^{-n}|\leq \left| \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}\right|\left|2^n+\frac{1}{2^n}\right|$$
and as $n\to \infty$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}\left(2^n+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}=0 $$
and the series converges pointwise but I can't show that it doesn't converge unifromly. I am thinking about using the Cauchy criterion, but I dont know how I should start.

$$\left| \sum_{n=m+1}^{k} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}(x^n+x^{-n})\right|\leq \sum_{n=m+1}^{k}\left| \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}(x^n+x^{-n})\right|\leq \sum_{n=m+1}^{k} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}\left(2^n+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$
and I can't argue that for $n\to \infty$ the sum of the RHS diverges.

Any comment would be very helpful.

Comment: You found a series independent from $x$ that controls your series and converges ... it is not difficult to prove uniform convergence now ...

Comment: Showing that the terms converge to zero does not imply that the series converges.

Comment: It suffices to show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n!}}x^n$ converges for $x\in (0,\infty)$.  Apply Stirling's formula and the root test.

Comment: I don´t know  Stirling's formula and also don´t know root test

Comment: Only know Cauchy criterion, Abel criterion, Dirichlet criterion, M test

Comment: Surely you know the ratio test.